# Openni "One or more of the following nodes could not be enumerated"

Tags: computer-vision, kinect, motion-detection, openni, primesense

I have installed the latest version of openni and NITE in the following order:

Openni 1.3.4.6 unstable development edition x64
NITE 1.4.2.5 unstable develeopment edition x64
Avin2 sensor kinect x64 from ../platforms/win32 directory

I use windows 7 64bit and I have connected Kinect and not using mock nodes. When i try to run an error: "One or more of the following nodes could not be enumerated"

My modules.xml contents are:

```
<Modules>
    <Module path="C:\OpenNI\Bin64\nimRecorder64.dll" />
    <Module path="C:\OpenNI\Bin64\nimMockNodes64.dll" />
    <Module path="C:\OpenNI\Bin64\nimCodecs64.dll" />
    <Module path="C:\PrimeSense\NITE\Features_1_3_1\Bin64\XnVFeatures64_1_3_1.dll" configDir="C:\PrimeSense\NITE\Features_1_3_1\Data" />
    <Module path="C:\PrimeSense\NITE\Features_1_4_1\Bin64\XnVFeatures64_1_4_1.dll" configDir="C:\PrimeSense\NITE\Features_1_4_1\Data" />
    <Module path="C:\PrimeSense\NITE\Features_1_4_2\Bin64\XnVFeatures64_1_4_2.dll" configDir="C:\PrimeSense\NITE\Features_1_4_2\Data" />
    <Module path="C:\PrimeSense\NITE\Hands_1_3_1\Bin64\XnVHandGenerator64_1_3_1.dll" configDir="C:\PrimeSense\NITE\Hands_1_3_1\Data" />
    <Module path="C:\PrimeSense\NITE\Hands_1_4_1\Bin64\XnVHandGenerator64_1_4_1.dll" configDir="C:\PrimeSense\NITE\Hands_1_4_1\Data" />
    <Module path="C:\PrimeSense\NITE\Hands_1_4_2\Bin64\XnVHandGenerator64_1_4_2.dll" configDir="C:\PrimeSense\NITE\Hands_1_4_2\Data" />
</Modules>
```

I also tried using the previous version of OpenNI and NITE with the same result. I also entered the license key in SamplesConfig.xml and it has no other changes. It has production nodes for image and depth and thats all.

I would like to know if Avin2 sensor kinect drivers work with latest versions of openni. Whats the order of installation and what driver do i install to make kinect work with openni 1.3.4.6 ?

thanks

-Siddharth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version of openni had bugs with UAC settings in windows 7. The latest version of openni which supports poseless callibration works out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check all dll are existing
2. Check your license key is correct (some modules need a valid license key). Register it with `niReg` command
3. Check all configDir are existing, readable, with their config files inside
4. Stop your program immediatly after `context.InitFromXmlFile(strFileName, scriptNode, pErrors)` (so you can do next step)
5. Comment all `Module` nodes. The error should disapper, but now you have a non working program.
6. One by one, decomment modules and test if the error appears. Now you know what is the bad module.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, but heres what i investigated:  

1) All dlls do exist, i verified with the previous build of openni.  
2) This is puzzling me. I thought i didnt need the license key for NITE as the newest versions didnt require for you to enter it. In anycase, I have entered the license key in the sampleConfig.xml using the license tag.  
3) I had encountered this problem before if I had installed openni in program files directory. I got around this problem by installing it in the root directory, example C:\OpenNI and C:\Primesense\NITE. So i have no read only issues here.

Comment: 4) It fails on InitFromXmlFile, but the error exists even if disconnect kinect from my system, making it believe that this is a driver issue.  
5 and 6) Done that and I still get that the primesense device is not detected and the enumerated nodes is not instantiated.  


Now I did notice that my laptop(Which is a HP elitebook 8760w) has an eSata usb drive, 2 ss usb drives and yet another 2 more which i think are usb 2.0. After some search , i found that kinect doesnt work with some usb 3.0 ports?

Comment: Eitherway, could you tell me the order in you installed your openni, nite and drivers? You have the sensor kinect drivers, avin2 drivers, openni has a driver installer in its directory. What should be installed and in what order?  

thanks

Comment: I'm using linux and I installed: OpenNI and Sensor. They works without NITE for depth map and simple hand point. When I wanted more advanced features, I installed NITE. When I installed NITE, it gave me "One or more of the following nodes could not be enumerated" because it needed a valid license. Even if the license was in xml files, it needed to be registered with `niReg`. Have you checked what module can't be enumerated?

Comment: I kind of figured what happened. So figured that i had to install the avin2 drivers available in the Bin directory and not the ones in win32\platforms. But after that i started receiving errors that it couldnt create shared memory. My laptop is an office laptop and when i logged in as system administrator, i was finally able to get the samples working. But when i logged in as a local user, it failed and gave me the error. So it seems like i have some sort of permissions problems..

Answer (score 1):

1. Uninstall all previous kinect drivers if any
2. Download avin2 driver from https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect
3. Run SensorKinect-unstable\Platform\Win32\Driver\dpinst-amd64.exe (or dpinst-x86.exe if your system is 32-bit )

Then run demo program (NiViewer) to test everything is fine..

That's all..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but for some reason the stable versions of OpenNI and the Middleware and Hardware are just not compatible with the avin2 driver.

I use Windows 7 x64 and when I uninstalled everything and changed to the unstable versions of OpenNI, Nite and PrimeSense Sensor, it worked with the 64bit avin2 (SensorKinect093-Bin-Win64-v5.1.2.1.msi) driver.

So basically, ONLY USE UNSTABLE VERSIONS.